# Flash uploader that can handle >2GB files?

Tags: flash, upload

Is there an open source Flash uploader that can handle files larger than 2 GB? ASP.net implementations like SlickUpload are not an option, and SWFUpload (and others that I've seen) do not handle files larger than 2 GB. Nor is requiring the user to have Java installed to run applets. This would be for both IE and Firefox.

I've seen a couple "large file transfer" sites that have a Flash uploader and claim to go past the 2GB limit (which is the limit for http uploads for most browsers) so I know it is technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you would need to roll your own, basically reading small chunks of the file and sending them to the server yourself.

Then code the appropriate backend to handle those chunks and put them together.

J

Answer (score 0):

Some server side scripts do not allow you to upload files larger than 2GB. 
Usually in flash when the limit is reached on the server side then you will get an IOErrorEvent from the upload class.

As a solution you could split the big file into small zips and upload one by one... and at the ends unzip them on server side.

You should consider also that uploading a >2GB file takes some time and having the internet connection failing at 95% will mean you have to re-upload the entire file (which is not so nice).

Have fun... ! :)